# How do I pass variables to powershell through node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell

I'm trying to runs specific parameterized powershell scripts. Below is a working example

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,child;

child = spawn("powershell.exe",["c:\\test\\mypstest.ps1 -arg1 1"]);
     child.stdout.on("data",function(data){
     console.log("Powershell Data: " + data);
});
     child.stderr.on("data",function(data){
     console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
});
child.on("exit",function(){
     console.log("Powershell Script finished");
});

child.stdin.end(); //end input
```

Here is an example ps script

```
param(
    [int]$arg1 = 0
    )

function test(){
    If ($arg1 -eq 0){
    write-host 'too bad'
    }

    If ($arg1 -eq 1){
        calc
    }

    If ($arg1 -eq 2){ 
        notepad
    }
}
test
```

But I need to be able to pass the variables as the arguments for the ps script. I thought this would work.

```
var str2 = "\"c:\\test\\mypstest.ps1 -arg1";
var str3 = " 1\"";

var mystr1 = str2.concat(str3);

child = spawn("powershell.exe",[mystr1]);
```

I also tried

```
function myfunc1(param1, param2){
    var mystr1 = str2.concat(str3);
    //console.log(mystr1);
    return mystr1;
    };

child = spawn("powershell.exe",[myfunc1(str2, str3)]);
```

But i appear to be passed back the variable itself, below is the output i get from the console

*Powershell Data: c:\test\mypstest.ps1 -arg1 1*

*Powershell Script finished*

And tried this

```
var str1 = "\"powershell.exe\"\,";
var str2 = "\[\"c:\\test\\mypstest.ps1 -arg1";
var str3 = " 1\"\]";

function myfunc1(param1, param2, param3){
    var mystr1 = str1.concat(str2, str3);
    console.log(mystr1);
    return mystr1;
    };

child = spawn(myfunc1(str1, str2, str3));
```

for the above i get an exception

*events.js:72*
*throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event*
*Error: spawn ENOENT*
*at errnoException (child_process.js:998:11)*
*at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:34)*

i'm not fluent in js so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str2 = "\"c:\\test\\mypstest.ps1 -arg1";
var str3 = " 1\"";

var mystr1 = str2.concat(str3);
```

...will generate the resulting string;

```
"c:\test\mypstest.ps1 -arg1 1"
```

...while what you want according to your working version is an un-quoted version;

```
c:\test\mypstest.ps1 -arg1 1
```

Remove the extra quotes from your string, and it should be equivalent with your working example.

Comment: wow, not sure how i missed that, that did it. Must have been starring at it to long. appreciate the quick response